# Add extended permissions - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Java program that retrieves users personal information and posts. I can retireve everything related to me but not to my friends.
I know that i have to add some extended permissions to collect information about my friends (e.g. friends_groups, friends_interests, friends_subscriptions and more) but i don't know how to add them. 
I didn't use Facebook Api in my Java application. I just give a specific URL, for example :

https://graph.facebook.com/friendID?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

and i get a JSon Object from this URL which contains the information of that user (id, first_name,last_name,link,name,updated_time) which are not useful for what i want to do.

I also tried :
https://graph.facebook.com/friendID?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&scope=friends_activities,friends_birthday,friends_status,friends_subscriptions,friends_work_history

but again it didn't work either to my Java App or Graph Api Explorer.

Can someone explain to me how to add the extended persmissions that i need provided that i created my app in the way i explained above? Can i add the permissions inside the URL that fetches the JSon Object?

Answer (score 0):

To get a person's data, your app needs to use that person's access token. To get that person's access token, that person must authorize your app (through Facebook Login). You can read more about Facebook Login in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3#login).